# What's the purpose of two exclamation marks before a variable?

Tags: javascript, todomvc

I'm studying the TodoMVC source and came across this helper:

```
// addEventListener wrapper:
window.$on = function (target, type, callback, useCapture) {
  target.addEventListener(type, callback, !!useCapture);
};
```

What's up with `!!useCapture`?

Comment: I'd suggest to read about false and falsy values in javascript. You'd know what it is

Answer (score 0):

The double exclamation mark forces a truthy/falsey value into a boolean. Think of it like `!(!useCapture)`, or not (not use Capture).